# How to custom Edittext android like caculator?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I develop a calculator application and I want customize my EditText like digital number in this picture:
[image]

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find a font matching the one you are looking for (just search for digital font tff files) and apply that font. How to do that can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need make the elevation and circle corner of Button,Try [Defining Shadows](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).And also the specific font or image instead to custom the digital number.